# Why is my urlConnection.getContentLength size always -1?

Tags: android, parsing, google-maps, kml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getContentLength() returning -1 on some devices and not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617507/getcontentlength-returning-1-on-some-devices-and-not-others)

I'm doing on an Android app that will show the the route from a place to another place. 
So firstly I need to get the kml file and then parse in. However, my parse size is -1 which is not suppose to be so. The parse size must be bigger than -1 but I couldn't get it. Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

```
// connect to map web service
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
    urlString.append("&saddr=");//from
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append("&daddr=");//to
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
    Log.d("DrawPath","URL="+urlString.toString());

    // get the kml (XML) doc. And parse it to get the coordinates(direction route).
    Document doc = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
    URL url = null;

    try
    {
        url = new URL(urlString.toString());
        urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Log.d("Before parse", "size:" + urlConnection.getContentLength());
        doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617507/getcontentlength-returning-1-on-some-devices-and-not-others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418106/getcontentlength-return-1-only-in-wifi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428639/url-connection-returning-negative-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the correct latitude and longitude values for this. I could do this with your code. I tried passing Longitude and latitude values corrected up to 7 decimal points. I tried [this](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=18.4577015,73.8552158&daddr=19.017576,72.8562427&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml).

Try with following.
Pune = >   srcLat = 18.4577015;
Pune = >   srcLong = 73.8552158;

Mumbai = > destLat = 19.017576;
Mumbai = > destLong = 72.8562427;

Result: Before parse size:47555

Comment: I tried yours but still got parse size: -1. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: If you tried with my values then we shoud get the same URL.I have added the URL above ,try at your end compare the URL which your code is preparing.